# JavaFX how to get menubar to fit to parent in width only?

Tags: java, resize, javafx, menubar, autoresize

I am using Scene Builder to create my GUI and my menu bar isn't resizing to the parent. How do i get it to do this?

When I try Modify -> Fit to Parent, the menu bar takes up the whole root pane, and obviously this isn't what i want. Here is an image of what i am talking about:

[image]

As you can see, the menu bar doesn't fully extend to the end of the window.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had to set the anchor pane constraints in the menu bar. I had to make the left and right margins zero:

[image]

Comment: What most of us are missing here, is that the  menuBar has to be a direct child of the AnchorPane. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This solution works without coding, using only scene builder, which is what j will and I were both looking for. Not obvious in scene builder I have to say!

Answer (score 15):

You need to bind the preferred width property of your menu bar to the `width` of your stage or some other container node. It works when you dynamically resize too.

```
menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());
```

Answer (score 3):

[image: MenuBar][image: HBox][image: Wrapping]Here is another way to do it. Wrap MenuBar in a HBOX. Set MenuBar's HGrow to ALWAYS. Set HBOX Node Alignment to TOPLEFT.

Comment: that's not a bad idea.

Comment: I think you should mark this question as an answered question.

Comment: This doesn't work when the frame is re-sized at run-time.